# What unit and dimension for membrane permeability / permeation expression?

Tags: gas-laws, diffusion

### Context

When studying the diffusion of gases through thin membrane, one may use the diffusion coefficient $D$ used in [Fick's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fick%27s_laws_of_diffusion) as (one dimension form):

\begin{equation}
J = - D \cdot\frac{d\varphi}{dx}
\end{equation}

wherein:

- $J$ is the diffusion flux (mol.m$^2$.s$^{-1}$)
- $D$ is the diffusion coefficient (m$^2$.s$^{-1}$)
- $\varphi$ is the concentration (mol.m$^{-3}$)
- $x$ is the position

While this expression describes well what happens locally, it can be integrated over a membrane's thickness leading to:

\begin{equation}
J = \frac{D}{e} \cdot (\varphi(x=0) - \varphi(x=e))
\end{equation}

wherein $e$ is the membrane thickness and the membrane is located between $x=0$ and $x=e$. While $D$ is an **intrinsic property** of the membrane, if we only have access to the concentrations $\varphi$ before and after the membrane, it is the $D/e$ ratio that is of importance when studying the influence of the membrane on the diffusion flux $J$.

I am working on biological membrane samples of variable thicknesses. Thicknesses which I cannot—and do not want to$^a$—measure. Thus, from my external point of view, I can only measure the $D/e$ ratio to characterise the permeability of the membranes. Let:

\begin{equation}
X = \frac{D}{e}
\end{equation}

of unit m.s$^{-1}$.

---

### Question

Hesitating between conductivity, permeability / permeation and diffusivity, I was wondering:

**What would be the logical name for X?**

Indeed, I came across several denominations for values expressing the same kind of phenomena:

- [Permeation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permeation) and the definition of the [barrer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrer) would lead me to think that $X$ is in fact analogous to the **permeance** of the membranes. Still, even at STP$^b$, the unit of permeance is m.s$^{-1}$.Pa$^{-1}$ while $X$ does not have the *pressure* dimension.
- Maybe I could use the term *lineic diffusion coefficient*.
- I also saw the [hydraulic conductivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydraulic_conductivity) which has a unit of m.s$^{-1}$. However, If I understood well, it is linked to the behaviour of fluids flow in porous media, while I think it is diffusion which drives gas transport in thin membranes.

**Does it make sense to you to use one of these $X$ definitions to characterise my membrane? Or should I better normalise it with ambient pressure, yielding a more conventional permeance?**

Any advice would be welcome. If I do agree that any unit and name can fit as long as it is justified, I would also like to know what are the best practice when characterising thin membranes and what units are the most used to address such issues. I wouldn't want to use a misleading name that could loose the reader. Diffusion and permeation coefficients seems to be common[1-2] but I would like an external opinion on the matter, especially because I cannot access my membranes' thicknesses.

---

### Footnotes and References

$^a$: even if I *could* measure the thickness of the membranes at some point, the idea is to build a general model that can be used without having to measure this thickness in real life condition. The only thing that matters for me is the *actual* gas diffusion rate through this membrane (in cm$^3$.cm$^{-2}$.s$^{-1}$).

$^b$: Standard Temperature and Pressure conditions.

1. Pasternak et al., *Diffusion and Permeation of Oxygen, Nitrogen, Carbon Dioxide, and Nitrogen Dioxide through Polytetrafluoroethylene*, **1970**, DOI: [10.1021/ma60015a020](https://doi.org/10.1021/ma60015a020)
2. Neela et al., *Permeability, diffusivity and solubility of carbon dioxide in fluoropolymers: an experimental and modeling study*, **2014**, DOI: [10.1007/s10965-014-0401-z](http://www.dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10965-014-0401-z)

Comment: Why give it a name at all ? Only D is a property of the membrane's structure/ composition.

Comment: @porphyrin Because: (i) I cannot access D because I cannot access the thickness e, so D alone is not an option and (ii) it is convenient to use a name to refer to things in general. In particular if X is my figure of merit, I want to refer to it, and give it an appropriate name.